# Time operation in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here's what I want to do and I realized it wasn't working.

```
If Time > 23 And Time < 7 Then
   ws.Cells(Target.Row, 12).Value = 3
ElseIf Time > 7 And Time < 15 Then
   ws.Cells(Target.Row, 12).Value = 1
Else
   ws.Cells(Target.Row, 12).Value = 2
End If
```

What I want to do with this stuff... if the actual time is over 11 PM but less than 7 am... it writes 3 in a cell... and so on... The problem is that I realized that this comporison Time > 23 or Time < 7 doesn't work... how can I compare Time function with the actual hour?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try

```
If Hour(now) > 23 or Hour(now) <= 7 Then
   ws.Cells(Target.Row, 12).Value = 3
ElseIf Hour(now) > 7 And Hour(now) < 15 Then
   ws.Cells(Target.Row, 12).Value = 1
Else
   ws.Cells(Target.Row, 12).Value = 2
End If
```

Comment: Hour can't be greater than 23 *and* less than 7... :-)

Comment: @PhilPursglove right you are I corrected my mistake. Should know better than copy and paste lol

Comment: that was the solution I thinked off right after I asked the question! thanks!

Comment: You need to cater for a condition equal to 7 hours as well - at the moment this caters for <7 and > 7 so when it is exactly 7 it will end up on the third condition and put in 2

Answer (score 3):

Something like this. I have used sample variables in place of Target and knowing which sheet `ws` was

```
Sub Timing()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dbTime As Double
    Set ws = Sheets(1)
    dbTime = Time
    If dbTime > 23 / 24 Or dbTime < 7 / 24 Then
        ws.Cells(1, 12).Value = 3
    ElseIf dbTime >= 7 / 24 And dbTime < 15 / 24 Then
        ws.Cells(1, 12).Value = 1
    Else
        ws.Cells(1, 12).Value = 2
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @andreiIon I do recommend setting `Time` to a constant - as depending on how long your code is there is a chance (albeit very small) that a dynamic variable will change its value as the code executes causing an incosistency

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the hour from the time, which you can do with the `DatePart` function e.g.

```
Dim CurrentHour
CurrentHour = DatePart("h", Time)

If CurrentHour > 23 Or CurrentHour < 7 Then
....
```